# How to configure ADFS to send multiple roles for user

Tags: adfs, adfs3.0

I would like to know if there is way to configure Microsoft ADFS to assgined more than one  roles user. Can I get the corresponding SAMLResponse XML for this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ADFS claims rules "Token Groups as xxx".

Map one of these to Role - depending on what you want.

ADFS will then send all the security groups that the user is memberOf as Role.

Comment: can you share the xml send by ADFS for this as an example ?

Comment: If a user is a memberOf groups A, B and C, you get three claims of type "Role" with values A, B and C.